# Алгоритмы Java сумма диапазона

Tags: java, алгоритм

Изучаю Java несколько месяцев, ранее не имел опыта программирования вообще. Как и любой другой начинающий студент, я практикуюсь на Codewars

Попалась мне задача, совсем не сложная.
Есть int a  и int b. Нужно найти сумму чисел в диапазоне между a и b, включая их. Инты могут быть и положительные и отрицательные.
Если a==b  то возвращаем a или b, неважно.

Я конечно ее решил, так сказать брут форсом.
Ввел дополнительные переменные переменные, циклом сложил диапазон ...
Все это заняло у меня кучу строк кода и времени.

В решениях нашел элегантный способ решить эту задачу в одну (!) строку.

У меня вопрос, это нормально для собеседования, если я решаю такие задачи "брут форсом" ? Или все айтишники решают элегантно ?
Просто я не знаю, как самостоятельно находить решения в одну строку ?

П.С. В школу не отправляйте, меня уже не возьмут по причине возвраста ((

Comment: Все айтишники, начиная с маленького Гаусса, решают элегантно. Для этого нужно просто немножко учиться в школе.

Comment: Вы не сможете находить решения в одну строку, потому что Вы не знаете что искать. В школу Вы не хотите. Значит все - поезд ушел.

Comment: На собеседовании нужно решать так, как можешь. Я бы предложил решить брутфорсом, так как это очень быстро можно сделать и потом подумать про улучшения. Одна строка или несколько для алгоритмов не важно, если код легко читать и понимать и работает он за приемлемое время - то он уже нормальный код. Пытаться же 10 строк понятного кода упихнуть в одну строку непонятного кода я бы не рекомендовал.

Comment: @tym32167, с как пор формула суммы арифметической прогрессии стала непонятным кодом?

Comment: Для начинающего студента это в принципе нормально. Продвинутые знания инструментов тоже не с потолка берутся. В школу идти не обязательно, можно школьную программу с 5 по 9 класс и дома прочитать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, как знать, может там `IntStream.range(a, b + 1).sum()`, а не школьная формула))

Comment: @AlexKrass  с еще большей элегантностью !!! Класс. Через пару дней займусь стримами !!!

Comment: @AlexKrass, вообще не катит, потому что возвращает `int`, а в задаче надо `long`.

Comment: @AlexKrass, почему LongStream медленнее чем IntStream в 4-6 раз?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну сделаем LongStream и пару приведений типов, сложно что-ли... Я к чему, мы не знаем какие задачи в будущем встретит ТС и какой набор знаний от него может потребоваться. И какие решения на своем пути он встретит. И не факт, что все будет решаться одной школьной формулой. В принципе знания приобретаются постепенно, как и опыт, поэтому зацикливаться начинающему на красивом коде явно не стоит. Может потом, да.

Comment: @AlexKrass, он во время не лезет - я привёл в ответе ссылки на ideone. Запускал дважды - получил 4.46 и 3.65, что далеко не меньше 1, как с IntStream. Кстати, могу отдельным вопросом задать, если хочешь.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну не знаю, на собеседовании кандидата в джуны вроде никто по времени на секунды не ограничивает) Я повторю, я отвечаю по ситуации в целом, а не по конкретной встретившейся задаче. Мы просто друг друга недопоняли. Вопрос автора ведь тоже оффтопик "всегда ли пишут красивый и компактный код и нормально ли городить огород для начинающего", а не по конкретной задаче.

Comment: @Qwertiy, по поводу скорости, это как я понимаю связано с реализацией самой Java машины, поскольку исходный код выглядит одинаково у стримов. В общем не могу сказать, если найдешь ответ, маякни.

Comment: @Qwertiy я кода автора не видел же, не могу знать, понятный он или нет.

Comment: Весь вопрос в том, что от вас хотели... Код? Элементарные знания математики? Лично я вижу одно нормальное решение — `(a+b)*(b-a+1)/2`, и никаких циклов, никаких стримов... Ну разве что если на грани фола (сумма почти выходит за рамки представления) — сначала поделить на 2 четную скобку, а потом множить.

Answer (score 4):

Хорошие программисты математику знают и используют при необходимости.

Я вообще удивлён, что подсчёт в цикле прошёл по времени: обычно на эту задачу выставляют ограничения -10<sup>9</sup>...10<sup>9</sup>, а цикл на 10<sup>9</sup> операций - штука не быстрая, особенно для джавы.

Я на си чисто из любопытства (скучно было ждать конца пробного тура) пытался подсунуть цикл - это действительно прокатило, но у си и джавы производительность отличается значительно. Хотя, может такие штуки с тех пор и пооптимизировали.

Проверил. Джава, вроде, [считает за .77 секунды](https://ideone.com/6kcnpQ). Си++ слишком умный и [считает при компиляции](https://ideone.com/DhGs0F), так что добавляем считывание и [получаем .29 секунды](https://ideone.com/XzwwB3) - примерно в 2 раза быстрее. Но в стандартный TL в секунду всё укладывается... А вот джавовская версия с `LongStream` [работает аж 3.65 - 4.46 секунды](https://ideone.com/EUuKzG). Интересно, что версия с `IntStream` [вполне успевает за .86](https://ideone.com/bqKZrA), но может давать неверный результат.

using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
      int l = -1000000000, r = 1000000000;
      long long res = 0;
      for (int x=l; x

    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
      int l, r;
      cin >> l >> r;
      long long res = 0;
      for (int x=l; x

Что касается элегантности в целом, то не все и не всегда. Да и вообще у разных программистов понятие элегантности разное. Да и критерии элегантности могут отличаться в зависимости от назначения программы.

Впрочем, не только элегантности. Во многих алгоритмических задачах при выборе алгоритма будет стоять выбор между памятью и скоростью. Лично я предпочитаю скорость. А во многих задачах ничто из этого не требуется, зато можно написать красивый код или красиво построить архитектуру (это уже не про олимпиадные задачи).

В олимпиадных задачах как правило имеет значение только асимптотика, поскольку на менее эффективное, но асимптотически верное решение закладывается запас при построении тестов и установке лимита по времени. Насколько я знаю, обычно делается выбор в пользу возможности ухитриться упихать асимптотически худшее решение (но это не будет просто сделать) против возможности случайно зарубить неэффективное асимптотически верное.

Но в твоём примере желаемая асимптотика `O(1)`, а твоя `O(res)`. Хотя может в пробной задаче ограничения специально понизили.

Comment: Блин.. Не получается кусок кода в markdown-комментарий загнать... Баг на мете: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11797/178988

Comment: Посмотри тут https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites блок "Are HTML comments supported?".